# Identify APIs inside functions

Tags: ida-plugin

I know it's a silly question

I'm using IDA and I want to know if there is a plugin to identify all called APIs inside a function instead of entering each function manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an overview of called API in a function you can use Graph feature without pluging :

- select function
- click on menu `View > Graphs > Users xrefs chart...`
- in `Starting Direction` check only `Cross references from`
- in `Ignore` group, check all except `Externals`

[image]

[image]

Comment: woow amazing ! ...... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about a plugin. But, [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9355) gives an IDC script for similar purpose.

I also wrote a script to get called function graph a long time ago. You can leverage this and tweak this according to your needs (idapython).

```
def generate_graph():
        callees = {}
        # loop through all functions
        for ea in idautils.Functions():
            function = idc.get_func_name(ea)
            callees[function] = set()
            for h in idautils.FuncItems(ea):
                for xref in idautils.XrefsFrom(h, 0):
                    callees[function].add(idc.get_func_name(xref.to))
        return callees
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try it

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to dump the import table at runtime using ollydbg and load it into your ida using a script. I used to copy the data (address and function name) from ollydbg's import table and parse it into ida using a script I wrote. I can't quite find the script anymore though..