# How to get symbol in IDA like done in BN code

Tags: idapython

I am converting BN code into IDA Pro and stuck at this point,
following are lines in the code which gives the symbol call

```
#####Get call symbol (if it exists)
dr.get_symbol(inst.tokens)
```

and

```
####### NOTE: Might contain FPs. E.g., "call [ebx + 0x4]"
#####Extract call symbol if it exists
def get_symbol(self, token):
    token = [str(t) for t in token]
    if '[' not in token:
         return

start = token.index('[')
end = token.index(']')
symbol = ' '.join(token[start+1:end])
self.api.append(symbol)
```

I want to convert the above code and want the following output in TXT file, but I am getting only strings and not in the register format like below.

**Sample output:**

> ```
> ---------------** 
>
>  ++++++ API Features ++++++
>     APIs: ebp + 0x8  { arg2 };eax;ecx;ecx + esi;ebp - 0x18  { var_1c }
>  
> ++++++ API Features ++++++
>     APIs: ebp + 0x8  { arg1 };edi
> ```

Comment: Hmm. I am sorry for not putting question properly. Sir, I have rewritten an existing code of BN into IDAPYTHON. In this step, i have done 1. networkx , mnemonic of instruction, basic block listing and getting assembly of each addresses.  All my work is in initial phase. Now i am conversion symbol translation code into

Comment: IDAPYTON and got following code as a help from internet.                             symbols = {}
for addr, name in idautils.Names():
    symbols[addr] = name
    symbol.write( 'symbol at 0x%x is name %s\n' % (addr,name) )  and same problem is disused on the following link . https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/finding-all-api-calls-in-a-function.  I am new in this field so please accept my mistakes .

Comment: You should edit the question instead of adding comments if something is wrong with it.